# Question on exponential function and random variable

Tags: python, matplotlib, exponential

I am trying to understand the following code. Could someone explain what each step essentially means? (especially the 1st, 2nd and 4th line of code)

```
X = stats.expon(scale=10)
xs = X.rvs(100000)
plt.figure(figsize=(10, 4))
plt.hist(xs, bins=100, color="navy")
plt.xlim(0, 80);
```

This was a sample code from a data science course and I am trying to understand the syntax.

Comment: Could you provide the full code? What is `stats` ?

Comment: Do you want to understand the syntax, or the meaning?  The syntax is pretty clear.  These are five function calls, with parameters.  Some have named parameters, some are positional.  The first two return values that are used later.